# PostgreSQL: Splitting long UPDATE to several commit batches

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL SQL `UPDATE` statement I need to run when I am migrating tables to a new structure.

The statement itself is simple and copying data from one table to another over FOREIGN KEY JOIN:

```sql
UPDATE swap
    SET denorm_value = b.value
    FROM block AS b
    WHERE block_id = b.id;
```

The problem is that UPDATE is touching billions of rows, making it impractical to be run in a single commit.

Does PostgreSQL itself offer any built-in functionality or tricks to break an `UPDATE` like this neatly to several commits? I can easily break down UPDATE to smaller chunks using `id` primary key.

Comment: Why is it impractical to use a single commit? PostgreSQL's implementation of MVCC makes it possible to do large `UPDATE`s in one commit - MySQL's does not. Maybe you are thinking of MySQL and transposing its behaviour onto PostgreSQL?

Comment: No, this took 2 hours for 25 million row sample. I am not going to lock my database to a `COMMIT` for several days.

Comment: Was your database not operational for those 02:25? Could you not query other tables? Could you not query the one being  `UPDATE`d? Write to other tables? I don't think your database is going to be `"locked"` for that time! What does the `pg_lock` table tell you?

Comment: Thank you. I already made a Python script that finished the same operation in few minutes using 100,000 rows commit buffer, but would like to learn if there PostgreSQL native way to do this.

Comment: What happens when you use a buffer of 1,000,000? 10,000,000?

Comment: It's still fast. But I just confirmed running the same statement as a single statement from `PSQL` console is indeed slow (several minutes and running), where as doing in from Python it is fast. I will investigate further. On the surface, I do not see anything obvious what is causing the disperancy. I will check the connection checking and such.

Comment: Please let me know your findings! PostgreSQL's MVCC architecture maintains a snapshot of the `swap` table before the `UPDATE` begins, so you should be able to work with the database, even during an `UPDATE`!

Comment: Ok, found this, gives som tips https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361291/slow-simple-update-query-on-postgresql-database-with-3-million-rows